# Bones are unresponsive after closing and reopening file

Tags: rigging, bones

I was doing this perfectly well, but when i saved and opened it, the bones do not work well for some reason. I probably skipped something. I just followed this tutorial and the end result when i saved was perfect; now, the bow is not distorting with the string.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpsd0Aw1qvA

The file: http://www.filedropper.com/levercrossbow

Comment: It seems the String bone is working, but the Limit Distance bone constraints in left_limit and right-limit aren't working.